# Decode google chrome cache file

Tags: css, google-chrome, caching, decode

I was wondering if it’s possible to convert chrome cache file contents to normal text. 
I accidentally deleted one important CSS file and I need it back. 
All I have is a file with lots of binary code. 
Is it possible to recover it somehow?

Some content of the file I have:

```
http://localhost/ateitiesklinika/css/style.css 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Thu, 03 Oct 2013 13:54:17 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13 
Last-Modified: Thu, 03 Oct 2013 05:13:33 GMT 
ETag "420000000161d8-3cd6-4e7cf3f54c270" 
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
Content-Length: 15574 
Content-Type: text/css 
0000000: 28 01 00 00 03 00 04 00 ab c3 26 ce 6c 46 2e 00  (.........&.lF.. 
00000010: e3 0d 27 ce 6c 46 2e 00 f7 00 00 00 48 54 54 50  ..'.lF......HTTP 
00000020: 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 00 44 61 74 65  /1.1 200 OK.Date 
00000030: 3a 20 54 68 75 2c 20 30 33 20 4f 63 74 20 32 30  : Thu, 03 Oct 20 
00000040: 31 33 20 31 33 3a 35 34 3a 31 37 20 47 4d 54 00  13 13:54:17 GMT. 
00000050: 53 65 72 76 65 72 3a 20 41 70 61 63 68 65 2f 32  Server: Apache/2 
00000060: 2e 32 2e 32 32 20 28 57 69 6e 33 32 29 20 50 48  .2.22 (Win32) PH 
00000070: 50 2f 35 2e 33 2e 31 33 00 4c 61 73 74 2d 4d 6f  P/5.3.13.Last-Mo 
00000080: 64 69 66 69 65 64 3a 20 54 68 75 2c 20 30 33 20  dified: Thu, 03 
00000090: 4f 63 74 20 32 30 31 33 20 30 35 3a 31 33 3a 33  Oct 2013 05:13:3 
000000a0: 33 20 47 4d 54 00 45 54 61 67 3a 20 22 34 32 30  3 GMT.ETag: "420 
000000b0: 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 36 31 64 38 2d 33 63 64 36  000000161d8-3cd6 
000000c0: 2d 34 65 37 63 66 33 66 35 34 63 32 37 30 22 00  -4e7cf3f54c270". 
000000d0: 41 63 63 65 70 74 2d 52 61 6e 67 65 73 3a 20 62  Accept-Ranges: b 
000000e0: 79 74 65 73 00 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e  ytes.Content-Len 
000000f0: 67 74 68 3a 20 31 35 35 37 34 00 43 6f 6e 74 65  gth: 15574.Conte 
00000100: 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 74 65 78 74 2f 63 73  nt-Type: text/cs 
00000110: 73 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 31 32 37 2e 30 2e 30 2e  s.......127.0.0. 
00000120: 31 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 01 00 00 00              1...P....... 
00000000: 40 66 6f 6e 74 2d 66 61 63 65 20 7b 0d 0a 20 20  @font-face {..   
00000010: 20 20 66 6f 6e 74 2d 66 61 6d 69 6c 79 3a 20 27    font-family: ' 
00000020: 6f 70 65 6e 5f 73 61 6e 73 72 65 67 75 6c 61 72  open_sansregular 
00000030: 27 3b 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 73 72 63 3a 20 75 72 6c  ';..    src: url 
00000040: 28 27 2e 2e 2f 66 6f 6e 74 73 2f 6f 70 65 6e 73  ('../fonts/opens 
00000050: 61 6e 73 2d 72 65 67 75 6c 61 72 2e 65 6f 74 27  ans-regular.eot' 
00000060: 29 3b 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 73 72 63 3a 20 75 72 6c  );..    src: url 
00000070: 28 27 2e 2e 2f 66 6f 6e 74 73 2f 6f 70 65 6e 73  ('../fonts/opens 
00000080: 61 6e 73 2d 72 65 67 75 6c 61 72 2e 65 6f 74 3f  ans-regular.eot? 
00000090: 23 69 65 66 69 78 27 29 20 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 28  #iefix') format( 
000000a0: 27 65 6d 62 65 64 64 65 64 2d 6f 70 65 6e 74 79  'embedded-openty 
000000b0: 70 65 27 29 2c 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  pe'),..
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's hex.

Comment: Please see this website:
http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html Your cache file you posted doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Actually it is a binary file see definition in wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file , iNfas just showed a hex dump of that binary file , so please do not be cheeky